# Is storing variables in session for global access is suitable if the data is large?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

Just to clear some confusion need an advice whether it is suitable if we use the session approach for storing global variables if data can get large some time?

Comment: By "global access" do you mean that all users get the same data or that each user "always" has access to his/her private copy? If all users read the same data, try using Cache instead of Session.

Comment: no the each and every user has to have his own private copy.

Comment: This may help: [Think twice about using session state](https://brockallen.com/2012/04/07/think-twice-about-using-session-state/)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it's not. Store the data in a db or some cache and keep only some Id in the session.

In general, you should be very careful about what you store in session. Here's why:

> The default behavior is to store session variables in the memory space of the ASP.NET worker process

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Storing big session data in memory could bring your production server to a crawl because it will soon run out of physical memory. Then you will be wondering where is the memory leak and spend hours looking for it.

I would advice not to use InProc session mode ever - in production or in development, unless you don't care about memory. There are some good Session State Providers available, i.e. [Redis Session State Provider](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/05/12/announcing-asp-net-session-state-provider-for-redis-preview-release/) - all you need to do is install nuget and configure it in the `web.config` file.

If you use any store other than InProc, you need to make sure that the data you put in Session is properly Serializable. And if it's not - it's better to find out during development than after publishing to production server. Thus my advice to use same Session State Provider for development and production.

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are not really suited for Session. The Session is per user so not Global. In addition to this the Session expires topically after 20 minutes although that can be controlled with configuration.

I would use the application cache for this, that is global and accessible by everyone. Plus you can control when to reload the data if you want that.

Now, the size of the data has implications as well. I would not put large amounts of data in the Cache.

The other option is to use a database and I would look into using a NoSql database. Typically if you cache a dataset, it does not need to be relational, the data can easily be serialized forwards and backwards so a NoSql db might make this quick and cheap